# can't ping to my public ip (I am using a 3G dongle)

Tags: networking, ip, ping

I found my public ip by googling [what is my ip](https://www.google.lk/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=what%20is%20my%20ip&ei=FC71VauKMcKyuATty6jIBQ) which is a google provided service(The IP is shown above the search results). I tried to ping that public IP from another computer that is connected to internet. These two computers connected to internet via two dongles. That is via two local ISPs.
What could be the reason for can't ping public ip from another machine? searching google wasn't help.

**UPDATE**

after issuing ifconfig command I found below address starting from 10(I hide it for security reason with stars).

```
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.***.**.** --> 10.64.64.64 netmask 0xff000000
```

when I ping this address from another computer on internet it says `Destination host unreachable.`

need to find why I got this message

**UPDATE 2**  (added by barlop)

It seems he has no router.

I don't know much about 3G dongles, but from comments, it looks like the OP has

E156G, HSDPA USB stick

He has two computers, each with one of those.

Here is the info that ipconfig shows when one of these dongles is plugged in.

```
Windows IP Configuration 

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Thakshi 
Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . : 
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid 
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No 
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No 

PPP adapter Mobitel: 

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Mobitel 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.224.54.236(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0 
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.70.210 
172.19.70.211 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled 

Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile broadband 3: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Card #3 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-2C-80-13-92-63 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : DC-85-DE-F5-9A-08 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-85-DE-F5-9A-09 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network 
Adapter 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : DC-85-DE-F5-9A-09 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 

Ethernet adapter Ethernet: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-B7-2C-32-4A-24 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface: 

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:2c86:35f0:f51f:c913(Pref 
erred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c86:35f0:f51f:c913%18(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : :: 
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 620756992 
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-56-9C-EC-1C-B7-2C-32-4A-24 

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8B737949-1FAF-41C5-BDD0-89FFA7B46483}: 

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

So his computer's IP is here     `IPv4 Address . . : 10.224.54.236(Preferred)`
And private.

The IP for under gateway lists as 0.0.0.0  in ipconfig /all

which I suppose confirms that he isn't using one.

And  whatismyip shows him a public IP  69.X.Y.Z

A public IP he is unable to ping

Comment: Sometime, routers block answers to ping requests for "security purpose". Do you have such a setting enabled ?

Comment: router could block ping. Ping can also be called ICMP.. Look for such a setting in the router.

Comment: @Toine42: I don't have such settings. I just connect to internet via modem sim. via local Internet service Provider.

Comment: If you run ipconfig on a computer, does it show the private IP or a public IP?  What is the make and model of this internet dongle? (maybe google has some specifics about whether it blocks icmp or not, or the manufacturer of the dongle might say)

Comment: @barlop: it's model is E156G, HSDPA USB stick. can there be any setting in dongle to become pingable? when I run ifconfig on my machine, it does not show the public IP which google provided as my IP.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The private IP is another matter and very separate and not any cause of the public IP issue.  I don't know if you'd get destination host unreachable from a computer blocking ping.  Could be, and could be your computer is blocking ping. Windows 7 does. I am not sure off hand the situation with iptables and ping/icmp.  But regardless of whether your computer is blocking ping or not, it won't affect whether you can ping your public IP.   The private IP tells me that your device is doing NAT though, and maybe it's a little router.  Or ....

Comment: Or maybe since it's 3G and you get a public IP, your ISP has carrier grade NAT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29098/discussion-between-barlop-and-lakshman).

Comment: You're behind a NAT. [Can I ping the public IP of a 3G dongle?](http://superuser.com/questions/856151/can-i-ping-the-public-ip-of-a-3g-dongle)

Comment: @nixda isn't the point of spawning a chat link in comments, so that additional comments go there?

Answer (score 1):

you are twisting the problem, its so simple:

we have 2 type of networks here: 
1)**sub-net** [devices like dongles and cellphones **in mobile Carrier network**] 
2)**internet** [mobile Carrier and every other thing **in world**]

ip types: 
1)**sub-net**: [private/internal/sub-net/local ip] 10.136.50.4 --> 10.#.#.# 
2)**internet**: [public/external/internet/worldwide ip] 200.67.49.24 --> #.#.#.#

and as we know you **cant directly access** to your device that is in **sub-net from the internet** because **it hasn't unique public ip** and in fact the public ip you have is your **mobile Carriers public ip**, that you connected to internet by them, and it means you are behind them and **they shared their one ip** to many people.

and if you want to **test ping** but doubt that if your dongle or OS accept it, you can **install free ftp servers** and try connecting to them by free ftp clients!

Extra help: 
search network typologies 
search NAT (Network Address Translation) 
https://superuser.com/q/1060928/578610

Comment: Your provided link is removed.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely reason why you can't ping the IP is that your router isn't responding to ICMP echo messages (read a ping). This is often done so people can't just ping every address to find active connections.

There may be a setting on your router to enable this, but without knowing hardware info it's hard to guess. A quick google of the router model number with "enable ping" might help you depending on whether anyone else has had the same issue. You could also check your router config page.

If that isn't it, I guess your ISP might drop those packets higher up the chain, so you can't do anything about it, but I suspect that is highly unlikely.

Comment: he doesn't have a router, it looks more like his ISP's router id doing Carrier Grade NAT